# Express cookieSession and Mongoose: how can I make request.session.user be a Mongoose model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express, mongoose

When a new user account is created, I create newUser, a Mongoose model instance that looks like:

```
_events: Object
errors: undefined
isNew: false
save: function () {
arguments: null
caller: null
_doc: Object
  name: 'Joe Smith'
...
```

The actual data for the object is in the **_doc** property, though getters and setters exist so you can run:

```
user.name = 'Jane Doe'
```

and that will work fine. I run:

```
request.session.user = newUser;
```

To save the user to the session. So far, so good.

However, in subsequent requests, request.session.user seems to be only the stuff in _doc. Eg:

```
name: 'Joe Smith'
```

Which is nice, but that means I can't run eg, **request.session.user.save()** to save changes.

I could simply make some middleware to look up the user associated with the data. But I'd like to know more about what Express and Mongoose are doing here.

How can I make request.session.user be a Mongoose model?

**Update**: my current middleware hack:

```
// Use as a middleware on routes which need users
// TODO: only needed due to request.session.user being saved weirdly
var rehydrateUser = function(request, response, next) {
  if ( request.session.user ) {
    var hydrated = request.session.user.save
    if ( ! hydrated ) {
      console.log('Rehydrating user...');
      models.User.findOne({ somefield: request.session.user.somefield }, function (err, user) {
        if ( err ) {
          request.session.error = 'User not found in DB!';
          request.redirect('/');
        } else {
          request.session.user = user;          
          console.log('Rehydrated user! All repos already being monitored.');
          next();
        }
      })
    } else {
      next();
    }
  } else {
    console.log('No user in session')
    next();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Express session is stored as separate storage and has limitations to what can be stored there. It cannot store prototype data (methods). Look at it more like `key<>value` storage.

Reasons for this is that session can be stored anywhere (pretty much), such as: process memory; databases (mongodb); redis; etc.

Because of this, once you put anything in session object and request is finished, express will take session data, parse it and stick into session store just as pure object. By default it is process memory, but as mentioned before - can be any other storages.

So when next http request happens, session middleware will try to restore session using cookie (if it is used) data in request headers, and will ask session storage to provide data back. As it is already formatted - it will not have .prototype stuff but just data (`object`, `array`, `string`, `number`, and other simple stuff).

So you need to create Model out of that data again.
You can do by middleware in express. So in `app.configure` straight after defining `session` <s>you can do this:</s>

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session && req.session.user) {
    req.session.user = new UserModel(req.session.user);
  }
  return next();
});
```

This will check if session is defined as well as user. And then will recreate mongoose model out of that data.

As mentioned here in comments - you should not store user data in session as it will lead to inconsistencies due to split of responsibilities over ownership of data.
So store just `ID` of user, and then using middleware load it from Database.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session && req.session.userID) {
    UserModel.findById(req.session.userID, function(err, user) {
      if (!err && user) {
        req.user = user;
        next();
      } else {
        next(new Error('Could not restore User from Session.'));
      }
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

After you can create middleware to check if user is logged in:

```
function userRequired(req, res, next) {
  if (req.user) {
    next();
  } else {
    next(new Error('Not Logged In');
  }
}
```

And use it like that:

```
app.get('/items', userRequired, function(req, res, next) {
  // will only come here if user is logged in (req.user !== undefined)
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Per the post I'm already making some middleware to recreate the user as a workaround (I've added my existing code to the question). Currently I look up the DB each time, a new model instance that was 'rehydrated' from the one in request.sesion.user won't save() properly since the ID already exists. I could use your solution and do a findByIdAndUpdate() instead of a save() but that seems really hacky.

Comment: Honestly - you could just keep ID of user in session, instead of all the data, and do load every time. Most solutions like passport.js do exactly like that. As ID in mongo is indexed - this query is extremely efficient. As well is better to rely on one database rather than on session, as user data somehow can be changed in meantime, while session will not know. So rely on database rather than on session for data - is more stable solution.

Comment: You are welcome. I've added code of how to restore user from ID as middleware with case of error restoring user from session.

Comment: You deserve another +500 for this answer, it was exactly the same issue I had.  It makes sense to save only the user_id, but I was concerned about server overhead.  A benefit is that when the user updates his/her information, it is immediately active and doesn't require a manual refresh.  Thanks for a very helpful answer!

Answer (score 2):

Even if it worked (which it won't, for the reasons Maksims detailed), persisting the user model instance in the session would be a bad idea.  If the same user logged in more than once, the two sessions' user instances would get out of sync and keep overwriting each other.

The right way to do this is to persist the `_id` of the user in the session (e.g. `request.session.userId`) and install Express middleware to load the user model instance into `request.user` so it's available to your other middleware and route handlers for the current call.  Similar to what you're doing now, but a little cleaner.

Looking up a single object up by its `_id` is incredibly fast and because you're doing it frequently it will already be in memory so the overhead is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Despite complexity issues with depending on your session store to hold the whole user object, it should be noted that you *can* initialize a mongoose object from a plain JS object using the `init()` method (as of this writing, v4.4.14).

```
req.user = new UserModel().init(req.session.user);
req.user.name = 'James';
req.user.save( ... );
```

**NOT** like this (it will try to save a *new* document with the same `_id`  rather than updating):

```
req.session.user = new UserModel(req.session.user);
req.user.name = 'James';
req.user.save( ... );
```