# Shoud I put a mongoose Document Object in session?

Tags: javascript, session, express, mongoose

I'm using nodejs + expressjs + mongoosejs for an web app. I have an idea but don't know it's right or not.

when user login into system, I query mongodb for authorization, that query give me back the user's document in json format as result, I could just ignore it and proceed to next. but I think I can use the lean() setting get the mongoose document object, and put it into the session. so if there are any further operation using user's info, I can use the one in session , no need to query it again. and if the user want to update his status, I can just save on this object, no need to findByIdAndUpdate, right? like this:

```
// This is the user login process on express
exports.login = function(req, res, next) {

    // do nothing if login info are not enough
    if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
        res.status(400).json({
            title: msgMissAuthInfoTitle,
            msg: msgMissAuthInfo
        });
    }

    // look up user info (the req.body has user's email and password)
    User.findOne(req.body)
        .lean(false)  // here I set it to false to get a mongoose document object
        .exec(function(err, user) {

        // pass if error happend
        if (err) next(err);
        // if the account not found, return the fail message
        else if (!user) {
            res.status(401).json({
                title: msgAuthFailedTitle,
                msg: msgAuthFailed
            });
        }
        // if account could be found
        else {
            // put account(the mongoosejs document object) into session
            req.session.user = user;

            res.json({
                msg: "welcome!"
            });
        }
    });
};
```

And, say, the user want update his birth day:

```
// This is user info update process on express
exports.update = function(req, res, next) {

    // Could it be simple like this?
    req.session.user.set('birthDay', req.body.birthDay).save(function(err, updatedUser) {
        if (err) next(err);
        else res.send(updatedUser);
    });
};
```

should I do this? any problem about this idea?
thanks for any tips.

Comment: See this similar question for why this would be a bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18512461/1259510